# Is there a way to cast video from one Android device to up to 2 other devices?

Tags: wi-fi, 4.1-jelly-bean, video-streaming

Lets say I have the following Android devices:

1. An Android smartphone running 4.1 with Wifi capabilities
2. (2) Android tables running 4.1 with similar Wifi capabilities

Is there an app that makes it possible to have the 2 tablets play a video file that is hosted on the smartphone?

The app or another app working along side it, would have to allow the devices to establish an ad-hoc wifi network.

The use case is that I would like to setup the tablets on the rear headrests inside my truck.  This way, the passenger can control the video being played to the 2 slaved tablets from a network-connected smartphone.  Are there apps out there that do that and if so, what are they?

Comment: Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see our [help/on-topic] for details). You might wish to consult [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) to find a fitting place for your question.

Comment: Ugh. This question is fine. There is a well-defined problem to be solved. That an app is being asked for is secondary.

Comment: Thanks @Izzy, I followed your links.  The Help center suggests this question follows the guidelines.  It says "Using a particular app on your Android device" is ok. I don't see "Is there an app for X" anywhere in the discouraged section.

Comment: Having read it again, I agree with Al. Consider my comment as non-existing and never made ("Mu"); I'll still leave it there to keep the context to Al's comment (so we can learn from my mistake).